# How to get Proper status code with laravel 5 API

Tags: api, laravel, httpresponse

How can i get the Status code while creating an API with laravel5.

Here is what i am trying to do.

return Response::json(
           array(
            'error' => false,
            'results' => $results,
            'status_code' => 200 etc
        ));

All i want to change this status code,as it may be 404,201 etc

Comment: #Waqas, You Means how to get query status ?  and than return that status back in response

Comment: If that is the situation ,than you should decide the status depends on the query result and return it with response.

Comment: Muhammad Sadiq: Yes exactly i need this

Comment: than check the $result, if it is empty than status = 404 and if not than set status accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You should set status code as second parameter, so return response like this:

```
return response()->json($results, 201);
```

Comment: But it will return 201 on every request ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common function like,

```
public function returnResponse($message, $statusCode)
{
  return response()->json($message, $statusCode);
}
```

or

```
public function returnResponse($message, $statusCode)
{
  return response()->json(['message' => $message], $statusCode); 
}
```

You can call like as ,

```
$this->returnResponse('ThankYou for use this', 200); //or
$this->returnResponse('There is an error..!!', 422);
```

You can use above like something, if you can use without function,

```
return response()->json(['message' => $message], 201);
```

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: I am having issue how do i get $statusCode ? once i get it then i can pass it to a function or use it where else need it?

Comment: @WaqasAli we have a various code, refer some web site and you can fix with that code. ex:- http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html